# How to scale up a random texture on a flat plain without duplicating

Tags: height-map

I have transferred a heightmap similar to wrinkles on a surface and now I want to scale it up to a bigger surface area. However, I don't want to replicate the texture but I want to reproduce it randomly on a surface so I won't lose its randomness (I don't want to replicate similar tiles to the initial image). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: how much bigger? can you show examples of what you have and what you want?

Comment: Now, I have the structure on a small square plain which is applied from a heightmap. The structure is wrinkle-like and random. So, I want to scale it up on a bigger plain and I want to reproduce the structure on the bigger plain, but not replicating it as similar tiles.

Comment: The reason I asked about the size was that if it is 5 times bigger or more then you will need to look at coding a solution or excepting tiles. Smaller and you can try stretching the existing texture or creating a custom brushes and painting the patterns on. It would also be helpful to see your current height map. Please add it to your question.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I didn't have an image at the moment but as soon as I have access to it, I will upload the heightmap. Your answer was already helpful, thanks.